# How To Increase the height of MDCTextInputControllerOutlinedTextArea

Tags: ios, cocoapods, material-design, swift4, xcode9.3

[image]I have assigned a class named **MDCMultilineTextField**  for Uiview from the storyboard. This class is used for Multiline TextView. My Uiview height is 400(not fix) but my UiView border is not same as height, Please verify my code and you can see screenshot below.

```
        import MaterialComponents    

        @IBOutlet var viewTextView: MDCMultilineTextField!
        @IBOutlet var btnDone: UIButton!
        var notes=""
        var dismissView: ((_ text:String) -> Void)?
        var desc: MDCTextInputControllerOutlinedTextArea?
       override func viewDidLoad()
        {
           desc = MDCTextInputControllerOutlinedTextArea(textInput: viewTextView)
           viewTextView.placeholder="Description"
           viewTextView.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellow
           if notes != ""
            {
                textView.text = notes
                viewTextView.text = notes
            }
    }
```

Comment: Were you able to ever resolve this and if so how?

Comment: found any solution??

Answer (score 2):

I have used MDCOutlinedTextArea and went through the same problem. Only way to specify text area height is by setting minimum and maximum number of lines.
And you need to calculate the number of text rows that can be displayed in your view as below.

```
    inpOutlineTextArea.textView.text = "Description"

    let lineHeight =  inpOutlineTextArea.textView.font!.lineHeight  // height for one line in textview
    let totalVisibleRows = yourView.frame.height / lineHeight   // number of rows that can be shown in your view
    print("lines -- \(totalVisibleRows)")

    inpOutlineTextArea.maximumNumberOfVisibleRows = totalVisibleRows
    inpOutlineTextArea.minimumNumberOfVisibleRows = totalVisibleRows
```

Answer (score 0):

You can assign `MDCMultilineTextField.layoutDelegate` to UIView container.
It will change the container size based on `MDCMultilineTextField` height.

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
NSLayoutConstraint(item: multilineTextField.textView, attribute: .bottom, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: multilineTextField.borderView, attribute: .bottom, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0).isActive = true
```